# matplotlib set minor ticks under Seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code to plot a series of subplots:

```
minorLocator = AutoMinorLocator()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(8, 12))

data = np.random.rand(20,5)
ax[1, 1].plot(data, alpha=0.5)
ax[1, 1].set_title('Simulation')    
ax[1, 1].xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
```

However, this fails to include the minor tick 'markers' on the plot. I also tried

```
ax[1, 1].plot(data, alpha=0.5)
ax[1, 1].xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
ax[1, 1].xaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
```

but it also fails. Since I'm working with seaborn styles, I suspect there's a need to override a Seaborn parameter but I'm not sure how. this is my Seaborn implementation

```
import seatborn as sns
sns.set()
```

How can I add the 'daily' marker to my x axis? These are examples of my plots:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seaborn `.set()` turns the ticks off by default. It uses it's `darkgrid` style, which modifies the [matplotlib rc parameters](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) and sets the `xtick.bottom` and `ytick.left` parameters to `False` ([source](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/f0349b1a7f1e022cb1da8b94f2e019f04eeed397/seaborn/rcmod.py#L280)).

A solution is to either set them to `True` globally,

```
sns.set(rc={"xtick.bottom" : True, "ytick.left" : True})
```

or

```
sns.set()
plt.rcParams.update({"xtick.bottom" : True, "ytick.left" : True})
```

or, alternatively, to turn them on for the axes in question

```
ax[1, 1].tick_params(which="both", bottom=True)
```

Comment: used the last option and it work perfectly, thank you very much :)

Comment: one thing to notice is that using `ax[1, 1].tick_params(which="both", bottom=True)` alone wont work. The way I make it work is by keeping `ax[1, 1].xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)`

Comment: Sure, those lines are meant to be *added* to the code in the question. Which is also the reason why having a consistent runnable code in the question is useful.

Comment: I'm just clarifying since at least one other person was interested in the solution and your original post doesn't make clear if that alone fixes it or not, but thanks for mentioning in the comments!