# How to set log scale minor ticks on xaxis for all relplot subplots after using .set

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, axis, relplot

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips['total_bill']=tips.total_bill*10**(tips.index/60+2)

sns.set(font_scale=2)
g=sns.relplot(data=tips,height=5, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", col="time")
g.set(xscale='log')
```

According to different params (font_scale,height,etc),
there might be some minor ticker for each 1/10 or not on the plt. [image]

How to make sure all minor tickers for each 1/10 be shown in all subplots?

like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48994101/7758804), except iterate through each axes.
- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52273856/7758804) explains that seaborn `.set()` turns the ticks off by default, uses its darkgrid style, which modifies the [matplotlib rc parameters](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html), and sets the `xtick.bottom` and `ytick.left` parameters to `False`, however the options in the answer do not resolve the issue.
- [`sns.set`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html) may be removed in future releases.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set(font_scale=2)
g = sns.relplot(data=tips, height=5, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", col="time")
g.set(xscale='log')

# iterate through each axes
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.grid(True, which="both", axis='x', ls="--")
    locmin = mticker.LogLocator(base=10, subs=np.arange(0.1,1,0.1), numticks=10)  
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(locmin)
```

[image]

### With `sns.set(font_scale=2, style='ticks')`

- See [seaborn: Controlling figure aesthetics](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html#seaborn-figure-styles)

```py
sns.set(font_scale=2, style='ticks') # or sns.set_theme(...)
g = sns.relplot(data=tips, height=5, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", col="time")
g.set(xscale='log')

for ax in g.axes.flat:
    locmin = mticker.LogLocator(base=10, subs=np.arange(0.1, 1, 0.1), numticks=10)  
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(locmin)
```

[image]

### Without Using `.set`

[image]

Comment: Thanks.It's working. And it may be better using ```ax.grid(True, which="minor", axis='x', ls="--")```.